# jQuery UI Sortable Question

Tags: jquery-ui, list, jquery-ui-sortable, sortables

I am trying to build a sortable navigation tree using jQuery UI Sortable.  I have it working great in Firefox with no prblems.  In IE it works pretty well, however, there seems to be some inconsistent issues when trying to move an item with a nested list down in its navigational tier.  The list doesn't expand to create a drop point for the list in motion and it often fails, however, sometimes the sort works anyway. I have played with this for longer than I care to admit! Does anyone have any ideas?

Here is a [link to a demo with source](http://ckeditor.ziplinestaging.com/sortable_teh_break.html).

To duplicate the problem: In IE drag the row (Move   Show   Item 12) up a few rows then try to move it back down to where it started.  (Note: to move items you must click and hold on move)

Answer (score 1):

You might get what you want if you try setting `placeholder` in the `.sortable()` call, i.e:

```
$("#list").sortable({ 
     placeholder : 'placeholderClass' 
 }
```

Then make sure you have a class `.placeholderClass` defined, and you can choose what styles to apply when a block is being dragged - Not sure of this is what you want - just a suggestion.

Check out [these](http://old.nabble.com/Placeholder-in-sortable-td19436314s27240.html) [pages](http://old.nabble.com/Placeholder-in-sortable-td19436314s27240.html) if you need more info.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that if you drag below the list and then back up into it it works just fine.  It must be some kind of jQuery UI  / IE bug.